# How to use "get user information" PayPal API?

Tags: paypal

In order to use the [get user information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#get-user-information) API, I have to pass the authorization bearer.  I can use this to get the bearer for my account:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "{Client-Id}:{Secret}" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

But what would I do for another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the `scope` [attributes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/attributes/),allow user to login to their paypal account and then you can access that user information.

The Steps are provided [here](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/php)

Try to follow the steps in this link and build your API calls.

Comment: Thanks. In the interactive tool, how do I get past step 2?

Comment: click the link in step 2 , a pop up window will open, copy the `code` in the URL and paste in step 3 `'code' => "{AUTH_CODE}"`

Comment: Oh, ok.  I was opening the link in a new tab.